# Group By , one row per record

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have data that looks similar to this:

```
ID | Order# | Transfer# 
1  | Abc    |   123a  
2  | Abc    |   456b 
3  | Abc    |   123a  
4  | Abc    |   NULL 
5  | Def    |   123c 
6  | Def    |   456d 
7  | Def    |   123c 
8  | Def    |   NULL
```

I want to run a query that returns 1 row, and it doesn't matter which transfer# is chooses (except the null).

If I run this query:

```
SELECT order#,
  transfer#
FROM coitem
WHERE order#   ='abc'
AND transfer# IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY order# ,
  transfer#
```

It returns:

```
Order# | Transfer# 
Abc    |   123a
Abc    |   456b 
Def    |   123c 
Def    |   456d
```

Is there a way to only return 1 row, either like this:

```
Order# | Transfer# 
Abc    |   456b  
Def    |   123c
```

My goal is to view top 1 transfer# for all orders in my system, with one query.

Thanks

Comment: [Standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) example of a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query (where the group size is one)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function for this purpose like

```
select * from (
select [Order], Transfer,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Transfer ORDER BY Transfer) AS rn
from tbl1 ) xxx
where rn = 1 and Transfer is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to express this but for me, the most readable way would be:

```
SELECT
   order#,
   MAX(transfer#) AS Transfer#
FROM coitem
WHERE transfer# IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY order#
```

I think this matches the idea you are describing.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I tried that, unfortunately some orders have letters in it, the max wont work properly

Comment: Max usually works on strings (`varchar`) as well as numbers. Microsoft SQL server?